# Ways to synchronize between audio and video

Tags: synchronization, video-streaming, audio-streaming, kinect-sdk

I would like to do a small video conferencing program with Kinect SDK. I am successfully get the video stream and audio stream. However, I do not know how to do the synchronization of these two streams.

Is there any way provided to do such task?

Comment: The Kinect SDK does not provide a way to record audio and video. The video frames are timestamped and your audio will be sampled at the rate selected rate.  Previous questions may help you in your search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583746/matching-kinect-audio-with-video